# Adjusting node position in force-directed graph

Tags: d3.js

I would like to have a version of my force-directed graph that utilizes squares rather than circles for each node.  The code I use to do that works fine, but rather than center on the square it draws each square with the upper left corner where the center of the circle would have been in a circular node.  Which means my text labels are no longer centered.  How do I adjust the x and y position of the rectangle object to occupy the same space the circle would have?

The code I'm using for both the circular and square nodes is below.

```
function nearest(value, min, max, steps) {
  var zerone = Math.round((value - min) * steps / (max - min)) / steps; // bring to 0-1 range
  return zerone * (max - min) + min;
}

  force
      .nodes(json.nodes)
      .links(json.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(json.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr('stroke', function(d) {return d.color; })
      .attr('stroke-width', 1)      
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke-width', 2);      
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        d3.select(this).attr('stroke-width',1);
      });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", function (d) nearest((Math.log(d.weight) *10), 10, 50, 5) || 10;})
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
          if (d === l.target || d === l.source)
          return 2;
        })
          link.style('stroke', function(l) {
            if (d === l.target || d === l.source)
              return 'aqua'; 
            })
        .duration(150);      
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        link.style('stroke-width', 1)
        link.style('stroke', function(d) {return d.color; })
        .duration(150);
      });

node.append("rect")
    .attr("width", function (d) {return nearest(((Math.log(d.weight) *10)), 10, 50, 5) * 2 || 10;})
    .attr("height", function (d) {return nearest(((Math.log(d.weight) *10)), 10, 50, 5) * 2 || 10;})
    .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color; })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          link.style('stroke-width', function(l) {
          if (d === l.target || d === l.source)
          return 2;
        })
          link.style('stroke', function(l) {
            if (d === l.target || d === l.source)
              return 'aqua'; 
            })
        .duration(150);      
      })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        link.style('stroke-width', 1)
        link.style('stroke', function(d) {return d.color; })
        .duration(150);
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a translation to the squares to move them left and up by half their width.

In your case:

```
node.append("rect")
   .attr("width", function (d) {return nearest(((Math.log(d.weight) *10)), 10, 50, 5) * 2 || 10;})
   .attr("transform", function(d) {
      var currWidth = nearest(((Math.log(d.weight) *10)), 10, 50, 5) * 2 || 10;
      return "translate(" + (-currWidth/2) + ", " + (-currWidth/2) + ")";
   });
;
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you -- I was trying to do it elsewhere in a transform and only getting my links to move.